# How to add custom UI elements (like checkboxes, combos and etc) to CesiumJS scene?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, cesiumjs

I want to add checkboxes to the main scene, each indicating a WMS layer. Selecting them will automatically initialize the provider with the layer info and add them to the map. Couldn't find anything useful on this. How can I achieve this? Is there any way defined in the Cesium API to accomplish it, or should I just create custom HTML checkboxes and render the scene everytime a checkbox is selected?

Thanks in advance fellas.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML checkboxes (or similar) for the UI, with Cesium API calls in response to events.

There is an [Imagery Layers Manipulation Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Imagery%20Layers%20Manipulation.html) available, that has checkboxes similar to what I think you're describing.

Also check out the [Sandcastle live code](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Imagery%20Layers%20Manipulation.html&label=Showcases) for the above demo.